# How do I add a bare-bones syntax to VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, grammar, vscode-extensions, textmate2, tmlanguage

I'd like to add the *simplest possible* (mvp) language grammar and syntax highlighting to vscode.

It's (imo) a mess of TextMate docs (two different versions apply) and random internet advice. I can't make a basic example work, or find one.

> How would I add a language grammar with only one rule (eg: treat "foo" as `mylang.symbol.foo`), and a single coloring rule that affects this symbol?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but maybe the VSCode Github repository might be a good place to look. I just did a basic search and noticed that on their [2019 roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Roadmap#editor), they mention simplifying some things related to the maintenance of Textmate grammars. You could possibly add some suggestions via their Issues site.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The grammar file needs to be declared in the `contributes.grammars` section of `package.json`, here for an example language `foo`. Since VSCode doesn't already know any languages with that ID, we also need to register a new language ID here:

```js
{
    // ...
    "contributes": {
        "grammars": [
            {
                "language": "foo",
                "scopeName": "source.foo",
                "path": "grammar.json"
            }
        ],
        "languages": [
            {
                "id": "foo",
                "extensions": ["foo"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

`grammar.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "scopeName": "source.foo",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "match": "foo",
            "name": "mylang.symbol.foo"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` command confirms that this is working as expected:

[image]

---

For `mylang.symbol.foo` to be colored a specific way, the extension also needs to contribute a theme in `package.json`:

```js
{
    // ...
    "contributes": {
        // ...
        "themes": [
            {
                "label": "foo",
                "id": "foo",
                "uiTheme": "vs-dark",
                "path": "theme.json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

With `theme.json` looking like this:

```json
{
    "$schema": "vscode://schemas/color-theme",
    "name": "Foo Theme",
    "tokenColors": [
        {
            "scope": "mylang.symbol.foo",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

After selecting the theme with the `Preferences: Color Theme` command, the word `foo` will be colored red (and `bar` is not):

[image]

---

Pretty much all of this should also be covered by VSCode's official docs on [Syntax Highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide) and [Color Themes](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#syntax-colors), but in more depth.

Btw, instead of JSON, VSCode also supports TmLanguage grammars in XML / plist format out of the box, but I find the former tends to be more readable. And actually, the most readable format to use for TmLanguage grammars in my opinion is YAML, since they largely consist of regexes and they don't need to be escaped there. This does however require a conversion step from YAML to JSON or XML for VSCode to understand it.

Comment: Fantastic answer. This would be a heck of a blog post. "getting started with vscode/textmate grammar"